# Тяжёлые файлы (видео) на сайте

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, файлы, mvc, filesize

Всем доброго времени суток.

ASP.Net MVC4
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: заказчик очень хочет на задний фон сайта поставить видео. А из-за того, что оно весит много, оно тупо не догружается до конца, и на сайте просто белый фон.
Дело точно не в кодеках: обрезал до 2 секунд - всё отлично воспроизводится.
Смотрел через нетворк в барузере - большая часть запроса это ожидание. То есть от сервера мы получаем не видео, а отказ его нам скачивать. Хотя у самого файла код 200.

В web.config прописал, но всё равно видео не прогружается

```
    <system.web>
       <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="90000000" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webserver>
       <security>
          <requestFiltering>
             <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="90000000"></requestLimits>
          </requestFiltering>
       </security>
    </system.webserver>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне снять ограничения на размер файла?

Comment: Может его на youtube залить? Например  https://codepen.io/ccrch/pen/GgPLVW и https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/PZyMrd

Comment: Пробуйте конвертировать (уменьшать размер) видео. Видео для фона указывается в нескольких веб-форматах (кроссбраузерность). Также, обратите внимание на мобильный трафик. Большие видео мешают получать ценную информацию, встает вопрос о целесообразности. P.S. К сожалению, по существу вопроса ответить не могу (как снять ограничения). P.P.S. Еще хорошо загружать фоновое изображение под видео - чтобы не было белого фона. Но это мелочь, не решение.